# как скачать библиотеку pwd?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Установил библиотеку python-daemon и написал

```py
import daemon
```

после этого появилась эта ошибка

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'
```

Как скачать pwd или есть другой вариант решения?

Comment: Windows небось?

Comment: да, windows 10.

Comment: Демоны - это явление из unix-мира, этот модуль работать не будет.